# Session Expiry on clicking Logout

Tags: c#, session

I am working with a Login Page(using c#, visual studio 2008). In which a user have to enter Name and Password.

After clicking on Login, it will redirect to Home Page.. Now, if i click on Logout, it is redirecting to Log in Page. It's fine till now.

My issue is, at this moment(after logged out) if i press `Back button` it is again taking me to Home Page.But, Here i want to get a message saying that

```
You are already logged out. Please Login again
```

it should not allow me to access Home page.

How to do it...?

Comment: what technology to you use? jsp, asp, php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
protected void logout_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Comment: @RanadheerReddy `logout_OnClick` is redirecting you to the login page. When you will try to press back button after logout `Page_Init` will do work for you.

Comment: ya.Thanks. that's ok. I want to know about the "three lines" inside the Page_Init method.

Comment: Before adding Page_Init it didn't called Page_Load method of Home page. But after adding the Page_Init method, it's calling Page_Load.

Answer (score 1):

In the header of all your application pages check for session status. I typically used the `$_SESSION['password']` variable because if the session was valid, there was always a password. Here is what the code looked like:

```
<%
    if(!Session['password']) {
        Response.Write("<script>location.replace('login.aspx?error=loggedOut')</script>")
    }
%>
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with c#, so the syntax may be imperfect. This should handle many different cases, including the back button.

Answer (score 1):

Can you handle onbeforeunload JS event on login page and prevent homepage display?

https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

Comment: But when i click on back button(after logged out), its not calling the page_load function of Home page.

Comment: onbeforeunload is Javascript event, so server side page_load will not be involved. You can check if top of history page stack is homepage and prevent history back button default action